# Double tap SHIFT key followed by a letter

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to be able to double tap a SHIFT key followed by a letter to activate an action. Can anyone help? It would be nice to be able to double tap either SHIFT key.

Something like??

<+<+ or >+>+ then d
do something
return

```
~Shift Up::
If (A_ThisHotkey == A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 500)
{
    Double_SHIFT := true
    Sleep, 2000
    Double_SHIFT := false
}
return

; Press a key within two seconds after double tapping the Shift key, to activate an action:

#If (Double_SHIFT)
    a:: MsgBox, This macro has not yet been enabled. Contact IT for suggestions.
    b:: FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,,MM/dd/yy - hh:mmtt
    SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
    c:: MsgBox, This macro has not yet been enabled. Contact IT for suggestions.
return
```

Comment: To have more than one command executed by a hotkey, put the **first line beneath the hotkey** definition and make the last line a **return**. See [Introduction and Simple Examples](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro) and  [Why do some lines in my script never execute?](https://autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#autoexec).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~Shift Up::
If (A_ThisHotkey == A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 500)
{
    Double_SHIFT := true
    ToolTip, Double_SHIFT     ; remove this line, if you don't want a tooltip displayed
    Sleep, 2000
    Double_SHIFT := false
    ToolTip                   ; remove this line, if you don't want a tooltip displayed
}
return

; Press a key within two seconds after double tapping the Shift key, to activate an action:

#If (Double_SHIFT)

    a:: MsgBox, Double_SHIFT + a

    b:: MsgBox, Double_SHIFT + b

#If
```

Comment: nice use of built-in variables and tooltip!

Comment: This works great. I had a problem where the other one triggered if you typed a capital letter twice in a row. This doesn't. Thanks. Two questions; 1.. How would you add to this so that either a left double shift or a right double shift would trigger it. 2. When you double tap the shift key or type any capital letter twice in a row, the tool tip pops up. Is there any way to not have that message pop up?

Comment: Ahh. Thank you. I've got the following now but can't get the actual date insert to work... Only a msg box. Do you know what's wrong with the code? I couldn't figure out how to insert code in comments so added to my original post above.

Comment: Thank you. I've got it working and above is my edited script. Could you help with one more area where it's failing? If you type a letter in between the SHIFT, SHIFT it will count. Is there any way to nullify activating the macro if a letter is typed in between the SHIFT, SHIFT. I guess you would call it an exclusive SHIFT, SHIFT.

Comment: A letter typed in between the SHIFT-SHIFT sequence always nullify the macro (Double_SHIFT).

Comment: Using the code above, typing SHIFT - ANY LETTER - SHIFT - D will still trigger the macro. Is there anything wrong with the code or something I'm missing? Appreciate your help.

Comment: On my system it works correctly (It doesn't trigger the macro). Try reducing the A_TimeSincePriorHotkey to < 300.

Comment: Strange, It definitely activates on multiple different systems in my environment. Reducing the A_TimeSincePriorHotkey to 300 or 400 helps a little but still typing a letter between the SHIFTS doen't nullify the macro. Using a single finger to test make it happen more frequently. Is there any other way to write it to ensure it must be SHIFT followed only by another SHIFT to activate?

Answer (score 0):

**Displays message box when <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> pressed**

```
~LShift::ShiftPressed()
~RShift::ShiftPressed()
$d::DPressed()

ShiftPressed()
{
  global t1,t2
  t1 := t2
  t2 := A_TickCount
}

DPressed()
{
  global t1,t2
  if (A_TickCount < t1 + 1000) && (A_TickCount < t2 + 1000)
     MsgBox Shift Shift D Pressed
  else
    sendinput d
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. If I want to add other actions to this after pressing Shift / Shift and then say a different letter like "f" Is there an elegant way to scale on this?

Comment: I suppose it would depend on the specifics of the other actions.  You could pass parameters to the functions.  If shift,shift,d means do something 10 times and shift,shift,f means do it 100 times, I would define two hotkeys:  `$d::DoSomething(10,"d")` and `$f::DoSomething(100,"f")`. Then define the function like `DoSomething(count,mykey)`